# Generic variable for architecture-specific structs

Tags: go

I have code that needs to run on mips and x86. To make things easier, I implemented functions with the same names and in `mylib_x86.go` and `mylib_mips.go` and also got code to build and work on both platforms. Below are some code snippets to show the layout of my structs.

In an attempt to further optimize my code, I declared separate structs for each platform in `common.go`

```
// lib/common.go:

// Struct for mips
type MipsData struct {
        var1 string
        var2 string
        var3    string
}

// Struct for x86
type X86Data struct {
        var2 string
        var3    string
}
```

I'd like to declare the relevant struct for an architecture by querying `runtime.GOARCH` in `main()` but the scope of the variable `data` is restricted to each block, thereby causing a compiler error like this: `error: reference to undefined name 'data'`

```
import "lib"
import "strings"
import "runtime"

func main() {

    if strings.HasPrefix(runtime.GOPATH, "mips") {
        data := common.MipsData{
            var1: "Mips",
            var2: "Something",
            var3: "Else",
        }
    } else if strings.HasPrefix(runtime.GOPATH, "amd64") {
        data := common.X86Data{
            var2: "Something",
            var3: "Else",
        }
    }
    text, err := json.MarshalIndent(data, "", "  ")
    // Write text to a file.

}
```

Is it possible to define `data` as a generic data-type in `main()` to overcome the compile error? Are there any other efficient ways of solving this problem?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply want to pass these structs to `json.MarshalIndent`, the simple solution is to declare the variable as follows outside the if statement:

```
var data interface{}
```

It will be able to store either struct, and is the type expected by `json.MarshalIndent`.  If you want to perform more operations that should work on either structure, consider defining an interface implemented by each struct, and using that instead.

Comment: Exactly the answer I needed. Thanks a lot.